# Linked list, making a pointer to an empty list

Tags: c, linked-list, sentinel

I want to make a linked list with sentinel nodes. The list structure must contain only the data, and the next pointer. My problem is, that somehow I have to create an empty pointer which points to a logically empty list. So basically I have to create an empty list. The function below somehow bad. Help me please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list* next;
} list;
list* emptylist()
{
    list* s1 = (list*)malloc(1 * sizeof(list));
    list* s2 = (list*)malloc(1 * sizeof(list));
    s1->next = s2;
    s2->next= NULL;
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Don't cast malloc, and don't use sizeof(type).  Instead, write `list *s1 = malloc( N * sizeof *s1)`

Comment: An empty pointer that points to a logically empty list is typically `list *head = NULL;` Sometimes it's useful to design the software so that `head` is never NULL. In that case, `emptylist()` should allocate one node `s1`, and set `s1->next = NULL`.

Comment: _Side note:_ What you're calling `list` looks more like an element/node of a list. Although, you _can_ reuse a node struct as a list struct, it might be clearer as: `typedef struct node { int data; struct node* next; } node;` and to define a list as: `typedef struct list { struct node* head; } list;` Then, `emptylist` would do: `list* s = malloc(1 * sizeof(list)); s->head = NULL; return s;` (i.e. no need to use _two_ struct allocations). Doing `list *s = malloc(1 * sizeof(*s));` is sometimes considered safer and/or more idiomatic.